# Triple nested list to a list of string in python

Tags: python, list, join, nested, flat

I have a triple nested list and trying to grab the same position of the most inner list elements and join as a list of strings by the second nested level in python.

```
input=[[['a b c'], ['d e f'], ['g h i']], [['j k l'], ['m n o'], ['p q r']], [['s t u'], ['v w x'], ['y z zz']]]

output=['a b c j k l s t u', 'd e f m n o v w x', 'g h i p q r y z zz']
```

I found how to flatten the entire lists but in this case, I like to keep the second inner list. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have so many singleton lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
inp = [
    [["a b c"], ["d e f"], ["g h i"]],
    [["j k l"], ["m n o"], ["p q r"]],
    [["s t u"], ["v w x"], ["y z zz"]],
]

out = [" ".join(s for l in t for s in l) for t in zip(*inp)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
["a b c j k l s t u", "d e f m n o v w x", "g h i p q r y z zz"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain`, `map`, and `zip`:

```
from itertools import chain
list(map(lambda x: ' '.join(chain(*x)), zip(*my_input)))
```

Output:

```
['a b c j k l s t u', 'd e f m n o v w x', 'g h i p q r y z zz']
```

*NB. I named the input `my_list`*